# how to rename label Name at run time is it possible ? in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have used label 1 to label 75 is it possible to change the  label name? example instead of label7 i want to rename the label name as label3 what is the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do rename the label name from 1 to 75 at run time in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657090/how-to-do-rename-the-label-name-from-1-to-75-at-run-time-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lbl As New Label
lbl.Parent = Panel1
lbl.Text = "Your string"
```

Answer (score 1):

It works in the form because you are calling `Controls` which implies `Me.Controls`, which is a collection of controls immediately inside Me (your form). Once you put the label in a panel, the label is no longer in the form's control collection, rather the panel's control collection. This is because `Controls` does not go deeper than the control it is called on. You could do this, which would solve your immediate problem:

```
' replace Panel1 with the name of your panel
Dim lbl As Label = Panel1.Controls("Label" & Data)
ReceivedFrame = ReceivedFrame + 1
lbl.Text = ReceivedFrame
```

But if the label is moved out of your panel, this breaks. The solution below is somewhat more costly in processing power but I use it everywhere this is not a concern.

Make a new class file in your project, and put this code in it.

```
Public Module Support

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
        Dim result As New List(Of Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(ctrl)
            result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
        Next
        Return result.ToArray().Select(Of T)(Function(arg1) CType(arg1, T)).ToList()
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ControlByName(ByVal parent As Control, ByVal name As String) As Control
        For Each c As Control In parent.ChildControls
            If c.Name = name Then
                Return c
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Module
```

It enables you to get all controls inside a control, which includes forms. Then get the control you want by name.

Then you can call it like so:

```
Dim lbl As Label = Me.ControlByName("Label" & Data)
ReceivedFrame = ReceivedFrame + 1
lbl.Text = ReceivedFrame
```

This will work as long as the control is somewhere in your form, in any container, or in any container in another container for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call by Name Property of the Label Control, what ever it may reside on the form. If the Label Control resides on a panel and its name is **Label1** then to display a value you can call it programmatically as **Label1.Text = "Your String Value"**.

If you want to access the Label Control's properties through an object then

```html
Dim lbl As Label = CType(Label1, Label)
lbl.Text ="Your String Value"
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It is a good code he wrote @Verdolino but is a little buggy because if you're control is nested inside of a nested groupbox that's still is nested inside of other control it will break.

but this is a pretty way to do it.
This is a recursivity function and it will look into the end of the 
nested controls.

```
Function GetControl(OwnerControl as Control,FindControlName as string) as Control
     If OwnerControl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
        '//===>It will loop in each control of the control container.
        For Each iControl as Control in OwnerControl.Control
             GetControl(OwnerControl ,FindControlName)
        Next
     Else
         '//===>this code is when the control is not a container and will check if the name macth
         If OwnerControl.Name.ToUpper =  FindControlName.ToUpper Then
               '//===>TODO HERE:Add here any code if the control was found
               ' you can register some events handler if you want
               ' AddHandler OwnerControl.Click, AddressOf _MyClickEventSub

                Return OwnerControl
         End If
     End If
End Sub

dim txtControl as control = GetControl(Me,"txtName")

If not txtControl Is Nothing Then
  '//===>TODO HERE:if the control was found
End Sub
```